# Continuesly descending lines

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to write a game. Now would like to implement not ending area of lines. But currently it animate 10 lines and reaches the end. I want those lines to descend like from up to down continuesly.

```
  public class GameSurface extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {
    public GameSurface(Context context) {
        super(context);
    this.context = context;
    // Make Game Surface focusable so it can handle events. .
    this.setFocusable(true);
    this.getHolder().addCallback(this);
}

public GameSurface(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    this.context = context;
    // Make Game Surface focusable so it can handle events. .
    this.setFocusable(true);
    this.getHolder().addCallback(this);
}

@Override
public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.draw(canvas);     

    drawingClickedArea();
}

void drawingClickedArea() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        canvas.drawLine(i * cellWidth + movedX, 0, i * cellWidth + movedX, getHeight(), pt.pBlack);
        for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
            canvas.drawLine(0, j * cellHeight + movedY+iter, getWidth(), j * cellHeight + movedY+iter, pt.pBlack);
            }
        }
    }
    iter=iter+5;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
void drawingClickedArea() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        canvas.drawLine(i * cellWidth + movedX, 0, i * cellWidth + movedX, getHeight(), pt.pBlack);
    }
    for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
        canvas.drawLine(0, i*cellHeight +iter, getWidth(), i*cellHeight +iter, pt.pBlack);

    iter=iter+5;
    if(iter>cellHeight) iter=0;
}
```

Works like a charm